# Spring Boot + jjwt security return nothing on bad request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

my problem is that I get nothing in response after sending requests with wrong login credentials or when accessing the endpoint without authentication.
This is how it looks when I send a good request:
[Good Response screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjil3.png)

And this is how it looks when the request body is invalid:
[Invalid credentials request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR7ps.png)

MyUserDetails class:

```
public class MyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new User("foo", "foo", List.of());
    }
}
```

Security configure class:

```
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailService myUserDetailService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Jwt Filter class:

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailService myUserDetailService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String requestToken = null;

        if(authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            requestToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromToken(requestToken);
        }
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(jwtUtil.validateToken(requestToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

And finally my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/auth")
    public AuthResponse auth(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Credentials", e);
        }
        final UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(authRequest.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        return new AuthResponse(token);
    }
```

EDIT:
I forgot to paste dependancies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.4'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I also have AuthRequest and AuthResponse class which holds username, password, jwt token and all the constructors, getters and setters ( not worth to past it here imo)

Answer (score 0):

You got to throw an exception while validating(following is what I use, just grab the concept, your classes and libraries might be different):

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(your_jwt_secret).parseClaimsJws(token);
```

so if your token cannot get parsed throw this and send an error response:

```
  httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
  httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("your_custom_error");
  httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
```

Comment: @DamianRecruit have you applied it?